# My Robot Has Escaped the Lab!

Tags: code-golf, math

My robot has short circuited somehow and randomly run off somewhere from my lab!

Luckily, whenever he does this, his shut-down sequence initiates, giving him enough time to randomly turn and run in the direction its facing for five rounds before he switches off. His gyro and accelerometer functions are still relaying the data back to the lab while he is still on.

The data will always come in the form of five sets of two numbers, for example.

`12:234,-135:47,-68:230,140:324,127,87`

Your mission, golfers is to a) simulate the robot's frantic run and turn sequence by displaying five sets of numbers in the form of `a1:d1,a2:d2,a3:d3,a4:d4,a5:d5` where `a`(n) is the clockwise angle (in degrees) such that `-179<=a<=+180` that the robot will turn from its current heading (initially it is at zero heading before it runs amok and turns for the first time), and `d`(n) is the distance in feet it has run before the next heading change which is such that `0<=d<=500` feet; and b) A calculated heading from the lab (which is also facing a heading of zero), distance in feet (accuracy up to 3 decimal places is strongly encouraged, -5 bytes if you do), and the orientation heading (in degrees) of where my robot it is facing when it has switched off.

Easy example:

```
Data: 0:1,45:1,90:1,90:1,90:1
Heading: 0
Distance: 1
Orientation: -45
```

The random turns and distances are just that, random. No set values are to be hard coded, we must see the randomness in action within the code.

Restrictions to randomness: No clock or date based references, we need to see a native `random` reference within the code. Whenever you run this code, the randomness must present itself with a possibility of showing 1 of 360 possible angles of turning with each turn-run round. So the robot may turn -36 degrees at one turn and may turn +157 degrees the next, followed by another turn of +2 degrees by another turn of -116 degrees and a final turn of +42 degrees on the final turn. At least 360 distinct values must be possible (between -179 to +180 degrees inclusive) with each random angle generation.

Restrictions to distance run: Similarly set, there are 501 possible distances the robot can run, (between 0 and 500 feet inclusive), so I expect the randomness to also be available when determining the robot's running distance. The robot could theoretically run 45, 117, 364, 27 and 6 feet with each of its respective rounds...

The data fed to you will always be in integer values... the robot will turn in integer ranges of degrees, and will run in integer ranges of distance. The output values however, will be floats...

This is code-golf. Shortest code wins... Now go find my robot!

PS: In reference to my "Accuracy up to 3 decimal places", if you can provide the heading (in degrees, to a MINIMUM of 3 decimal places) and a distance in feet (also accurate also to a MINIMUM 3 decimal places) you will get a -5 byte bonus).

Comment: All of your examples violate `-179<=a<=+180`...

Comment: @Doorknob Sorry, moment of weakness... Examples have been fixed...

Comment: @WallyWest Why -179<=a<=+180? What about -179.00000000...1, which is not -180 nor +180?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Seriously, dude? -180 degrees results in the same heading as +180 degrees from one's original orientation. -179 <= a <= 180 results in all 360 possible integer headings. If I wanted to go into unknown territory and narrow the field of possible angles accurate to 0.0000...1 of a degree we would be here all day...

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel and @OP - I'm probably going to get shot for this, but couldnt you use `-180 < a <= +180` as the `<` sign on its own means less than but not including AFAIK...

Comment: @GeorgeH You are correct, but what WallyWest is saying is wrong. "-179 <= a <= 180 results in all 360 possible integer headings" -> this is wrong because there are 361 headings. Or the robot isn't allowed to go to -180º?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel It is allowed to go -180 degrees, because that's exactly the same as 180.

Comment: The place is the same, the rotation is different...

Comment: Whether you turn -180 or +180 matters not, @IsmaelMiguel. The overall result means you will still be travelling in the same direction...

Comment: That is wrong. +180º means an half-turn clockwise. -180º means half-turn anti-clockwise (or counterclockwise, as you prefer). if the range is -179<=a<=+180, the robot can't turn 180º anti-clockwise. Why? He will be stuck at -179º! Maybe that is why he had short circuit...

Comment: @Doorknob, I'm spent... you want to have a go explaining to Ismael?

Comment: @WallyWest I'm not stupid and I understand what you mean. I'm just saying that the range should be fixed.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel This is *my* question, I decide the restrictions here... The range for the robot's turning will remain fixed at what it is. -179 degrees to +180 degrees. Case closed; lump it or leave it.

Comment: Well, I was just saying the range is wrong. You do what you want. But try not to break another robot ;)

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I agree with your comments 100%. But realise that the OP used degrees and feet, rather than radians and metres. He probably uses 12-hour time too. That probably means that his world view doesn't include half-open ranges. ;-) [Note to other readers: this is maths geek humour, not intended to be condescending per se. Also, I'm speaking as a user, not a moderator.]

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young While I appreciate the math geek humor, I intentiionally made the range -179 degrees to +180 degrees as I didn't want to make this easy for anyone. I didn't want them to re-use the "180" when golfing the code. Also as a +180 degree turn results in facing the same direction as turning -180 degrees I thought it unnecessary to double up.

I used degrees rather than radians simply out of choice and used feet rather than metres because it wouldn't have mattered if I chose one or the other. There was going to be no conversion to smaller units... So I went with feet.

Comment: I'm not clear whether the input degrees and distances should be integers or floats, and whether the output headings should be integers too, rounded to the nearest degree, or floats. Are either ok?

Comment: @Tobia, let me clarify that in the brief...

Comment: @WallyWest: could we please get some clarification about "accuracy up to 3 decimal places is strongly encouraged, -5 bytes if you do"? This part is quite confusing for us...

Comment: @MathieuRodic Provided. See postscript.

Comment: @WallyWest: sorry, but it is still unclear whether the 3 decimals are a minimum or a maximum...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Perl 6: <s>188</s> 184 characters - 5 = 180 points

```
$_=((-179..180).pick=>(^501).pick)xx 5;my$o;$/=([+] .map:{unpolar .value,$o+=.key/($!=180/pi)}).polar;say "Data: {.fmt("%d:%d",",")}
Heading: {$1*$!}
Distance: $0
Orientation: {$o*$!}"
```

Golf with whitespace:

```
$_ = ((-179..180).pick => (^501).pick) xx 5;
my $o;
$/ = ([+] .map: {
    unpolar .value, $o += .key / ($!=180/pi)
}).polar;
say "Data: {.fmt("%d:%d", ",")}
Heading: {$1*$!}
Distance: $0
Orientation: {$o*$!}"
```

Ungolfed:

```
my &postfix:<°>  = */180*pi; # Deg → Rad
my &postfix:<㎭> = */pi*180; # Rad → Deg

my @data = ((-179..180).pick => (0..500).pick) xx 5;
say "Data: @data.fmt("%d:%d", ",")";

my $cum-angle = 0;
my $complex = [+] @data.map: {unpolar .value, $cum-angle += .key°}
my ($dist, $ang) = $complex.polar;

say "Heading: ",     $ang.㎭;
say "Distance: ",    $dist;
say "Orientation: ", $cum-angle.㎭;
```

This turns the data into complex numbers with `unpolar`, puts the sum of them into `$complex`, and then gets the polar coordinates as `$dist`, `$ang`.

The cumulative angle, `$cum-angle` is collected because the angles are relative to the robot as it moves through the lab and because we need the final angle of the robot in our output.

Sample output:

```
Data: -73:230,-144:453,-151:274,-52:232,88:322
Heading: -5.33408558001246
Distance: 378.74631610127
Orientation: -332
```

The only real trick the golf uses is that it (mis)uses all 3 of Perl 6's special variables to good effect:

- `$!` is used for radians ↔ degrees
- `$_` holds the data, and anything that looks like a lonely `.method()` actually means `$_.method()` (except inside the `map {…}` block, where `$_` actually takes on the value of the number pairs that make up the data)
- `$/` holds what is in the ungolfed version `($dist, $ang)`. `$0` and `$1` actually mean `$/[0]`, i.e., `$dist`, and `$/[1]`, i.e., `$ang`

Comment: Nice! You can still go down from 188 to 184 like this:
`$_=((-179..180).pick=>(^501).pick)xx 5;my$o;$/=([+] .map:{unpolar .value,$o+=.key/($!=180/pi)}).polar;say "Data: {.fmt("%d:%d",",")}
Heading: {$1*$!}
Distance: $0
Orientation: {$o*$!}"`

Comment: @MathieuRodic Oh, nice find! Thanks! Unfortunately, the space after `.map:` is mandatory

Comment: Oh, I was wrong about the space, cool :)

Answer (score 10):

## Ruby, <s>274</s> <s>252</s> <s>249</s> <s>245</s> <s>214</s> <s>211</s> <s>207</s> <s>204</s> 202 characters (-5 = 197)

How did PHP beat Ruby in char count?! >:O Must find some way to golf more...

Edit: I beat the PHP answer, but the user who wrote it helped me do it! Go upvote him; he deserves it :-P

Another edit: Gah! He passed me again! You are a very worthy opponent, @MathieuRodic; congratulations, I have to let you win ;-)

```
P=(M=Math)::PI
puts"Data: #{([x=y=a=0]*5).map{a+=o=rand -179..e=180;x+=M.sin(b=a*P/e)*d=rand 500;y+=d*M.cos b;"#{o}:#{d}"}*?,}
Heading: #{M.atan(y/x)/P*-e+90}
Distance: #{M.hypot x,y}
Orientation: #{a}"
```

Ungolfed code (and <s>slightly</s> much older version):

```
data = Array.new(5) { [rand(-179..180), rand(0..500)] }
puts "Data: #{data.map{|x|"#{x[0]}:#{x[1]}"}.join ?,}"
x, y, a = [0] * 3
data.each do |o, d|
    a += o
    x += Math.sin(a * Math::PI / 180) * d
    y += Math.cos(a * Math::PI / 180) * d
end
puts "Heading: #{Math.atan(y / x) / Math::PI * -180 + 90}
Distance: #{Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y)}
Orientation: #{a}"
```

Sample output:

```
c:\a\ruby>robotgolf
Data: 94:26,175:332,14:390,159:448,-45:20
Heading: 124.52305879195005
Distance: 279.5742334385328
Orientation: 397
```

Comment: How is the robot facing due north after having turned five random angles?

Comment: @WallyWest I was under the impression that the orientation marks the starting angle of the robot, correct? I could make it mark the ending angle for only 3 extra chars.

Comment: No, it is always facing due north (heading 0) at the code's execution... 
Then it turns, runs, turns, runs, turns, runs, turns, runs, turns and then runs... before it shuts down.
It will need to have the final angle it is facing inthe `Orientation` section.

Comment: @WallyWest Ah, okay, edited. Is it okay if the orientation is not in 0...360, or do we have to do a `% 360` on it?

Comment: You can save 11 characters by declaring `M=Math` and `P=M::PI` and replacing the code accordingly - and one more character by getting rid of the space after the second `puts`.

Comment: and `x,y,a=[0]*3` could be `x=y=a=0`, no?

Comment: And move all output to one puts. That would give 252 chars altogether.

Comment: I can't believe PHP is beating Ruby either... But for now, it's true :) Also, according to WallyWest, you can remove 5 bytes if your accuracy goes 'up to 3 decimal places'; your program does not validate this condition (most answers on this page did the same mistake).

Comment: @Matheiu I doubt that's what the OP meant, so clarification may be needed. I think I'm going to have to let you win this one; I've been pushed to the limits of my golfing skills ;-)

Comment: Well, that's how I understood it... after some Googling: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures#Rounding_and_decimal_places. Regarding the golf itself, maybe you could use `hypot` for distance calculation...

Comment: @Mathieu It just says "accuracy" and doesn't mention anything else; I assume floating point accuracy would suffice. Thanks; that golf tip worked! +1 to you for that :-D

Comment: @Doorknob, %360 is advised... but I'll accept it... especially considering a -180 heading is the same as a 180 heading...

Answer (score 5):

## PHP - <strike>238</strike> <strike>232</strike> <strike>221</strike> <strike>212</strike> <strike>203</strike> 199 characters

```
for(;$i<5;$h+=$a=rand(-179,181),$x+=cos($b=$a*$k=M_PI/180)*$l=rand(0,501),$y+=$l*sin($b),$d.=($i++?",":"")."$a:$l");echo"Data: $d
Heading: $h
Distance: ".hypot($x,$y)."
Orientation: ".atan2($y,$x)/$k
```

(test it here: http://ideone.com/dNZnKX)

**Non-golfed version:**

```
$k = M_PI / 180;
$h = $x = $y = 0;
$d = "";

for ($i=5; $i--;){
    $h += $a = rand(-179,181);
    $x += ($l = rand(0, 501)) * cos($b = $k * $a);
    $y += $l * sin($b);
    $d .= ($d ? "," : "") . "$a:$l";
}

echo "Data: $d\nHeading: $h\nDistance: " . sqrt($x*$x + $y*$y) ."\nOrientation: " . atan2($y, $x)/$k . "\n";
```

(test it here: http://ideone.com/1HzWH7)

Comment: Looks like Perl just narrowly beat us both at the last minute. :-O

Comment: @Doorknob Yup, sorry :)

Comment: Definitely. Mouq, you kind of wiped out all our efforts with only 188...

Answer (score 3):

## Python - <strike>264</strike> <strike>259</strike> <strike>256</strike> 258 - 5 = 253 characters

```
from math import*;import random as R;r,k,d=R.randint,pi/180,[];h=x=y=0;exec"a,l=r(-179,180),r(0,500);d+=[`a`+':'+`l`];h+=a;x+=l*cos(k*a);y+=l*sin(k*a);"*5;print('Data: %s\nHeading: %d\nDistance: %.3f\nOrientation: %d'%(','.join(d),h,hypot(x,y),atan2(y,x)/k))
```

(test it at http://ideone.com/FicW6e)

**Ungolfed version:**

```
from math import *
from random import randrange as r

k = pi / 180
h = x = y = 0
d = []
for i in range(5):
    a = r(-179,181)
    l = r(501)
    d += ['%d:%d' % (a, l)]
    h += a
    x += l * cos(k * a)
    y += l * sin(k * a)

print('Data: %s\nHeading: %d\nDistance: %.3f\nOrientation: %f' % (','.join(d), h, sqrt(x*x+y*y), atan2(y,x)/k))
```

(test it at http://ideone.com/O3PP7T)

NB: many answers include *-5* in their title, while their program does not represent the distance with *accuracy up to 3 decimal places*...

Answer (score 1):

## Python 301-5=296

```
from math import*
r=__import__("random").randint
o=x=y=0
s=[]
for i in[0]*5:a=r(-179,180);d=r(0,500);o+=a;o+=180*((o<-179)-(o>180));n=pi*o/180;x+=d*cos(n);y+=d*sin(n);s+=["%d:%d"%(a,d)]
print"Data: "+",".join(s)+"\nHeading: %d"%degrees(atan(y/x))+"\nDistance: %f"%sqrt(x**2+y**2)+"\nOrientation: %d"%o
```

Nothing too fancy here, rather verbose. This is one problem for which I am not happy that python's trig functions work in radians.

```
> python robot.py
Data: 17:469,110:383,-146:240,-78:493,62:1
Heading: -17
Distance: 405.435748
Orientation: -35
> python robot.py
Data: -119:363,89:217,129:321,10:159,-56:109
Heading: -79
Distance: 130.754395
Orientation: 53
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2 = <del>376</del> 319 characters (-5 for distance=314)

```
import random,math
h=x=y=0
for i in range(5):
    a=random.randint(-179,180)
    d=random.randint(0,500)
    print '%d:%d,'%(a,d),
    h+=a
    if h>180:
        h-=360
    x+=d*math.cos(h)
    y+=d*math.sin(h)
t=math.sqrt(x**2+y**2)
o=math.atan2(y,x)
print
print 'Heading: %d\nDistance: %3f\nOrientation: %d' % (h,t,o)
```

sample output

```
-141:245, 56:355, 145:223, -10:80, -38:253,
Heading: 12
Distance: 559.031404
Orientation: -2
```

Comment: Python does trigonometry calculations with radians, not with degrees. Hence, your calculations are probably wrong...